# I need to create a complex relationship between two code-first entities but I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around it

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two entities and these two entities have two different relationships between one another. The first relationship is a one to many relationship and the second relationship is a many to many relationship. See the entities below.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Collection that represent this user's attached social providers.
    public virtual ICollection<SocialProvider> SocialProviders { get; set; }
    // Collection representing this user's friends from her attached social providers.
    public virtual ICollection<SocialProvider> SocialContacts { get; set; }
}

public enum Provider
{
    Google,
    Facebook,
    Twitter
}

public class SocialProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; set; }
    // Granted access token for talking to the provider API on user's behalf.
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    // User's unique ID at the social provider.
    public string ProviderId { get; set; }

    // The user that this SocialProvider belongs to.
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    // The users that have this social provider as a contact.
    public virtual ICollection<User> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

The workflow is as follows:

1. I sign up within the application. This creates a `User`.
2. I attach social providers (Google, Facebook, etc). This creates one or more `SocialProvider` and adds it to `user.SocialProviders`.
3. I import my contacts/friends from my attached social providers. This pulls down a list of social contacts and creates a `SocialProvider` for each one if it does not already exist and adds them to `user.SocialContacts`. In this case the `SocialProvider` will not have a parent user that "owns" it, nor will it have an `AccessToken` until a user signs up with the application and adds a social provider that matches it, in which case those things will be populated.

Will this work? I have a feeling EF is about to get very confused. I'm not very familiar with the fluent API or even most of the data annotations. Any suggestions for what I can do to make this work, or should I just make `SocialContacts` be a new entity called `SocialContact` that mostly looks like `SocialProvider` just to avoid any confusing relationship stuff?

Comment: it's a valid scenario so there should be no problems - rule of thumb - whatever makes sense to 'db' (in terms of fk-s, relations) it can be done in code first. You may just need to do specific configuration (fluent is better, provides more freedom). If you have cyclic references etc. you'll have problems either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**User**

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ublic string Password { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // Collection that represent this user's attached social providers.
   public virtual ICollection<SocialProvider> SocialProviders { get; set; }

   // Collection representing this user's friends from her attached social providers.
   public virtual ICollection<SocialProvider> SocialContacts { get; set; }
}
```

**SocialProvider**

```
public class SocialProvider
{
   public int Id { get; set; }        

   public string AccessToken { get; set; }       

   [ForeignKey("Provider"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public string ProviderId { get; set; }

   public Provider Provider { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("User"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   // The user that this SocialProvider belongs to.
   public virtual User User { get; set; }

   // The users that have this social provider as a contact.
   public virtual ICollection<User> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your DbContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
          .HasMany<SocialProvider>(r => r.SocialContacts)
          .WithMany(u => u.Contacts)
          .Map(m =>
          {
              m.ToTable("UsersInSocialContacts");
              m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
              m.MapRightKey("ProviderId");//If not ProviderId  try Id
          });
    }
```

I can't and haven't test this, so let me know the results so i can improve it. Ideally, you may have to pick this design apart and restructure it into one or more entities.